# How to center this div's content, which is created when a button is clicked and is inside a flex div?

Tags: javascript, html

When the form is submitted, the page content gets replaced and a Thank you msg shows up.
It now goes in a `<div>`, but set to its left.

Here's the resulting `html` part:

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="color:#373737;text-align:center">
    <h5>Thank you!</h5>
    <p>
       We will be processing your response!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the `javascript` piece:

```
function saveData() {
  var searchForm = document.getElementById('search-form')
  var page = document.getElementById("page");
  var table = document.getElementById("dtable");

  page.innerHTML = "";
  table.innerHTML = "";
  searchForm.closest("div.row").innerHTML = "<div style='color:#373737;text-align:center'><h5>Thank you!</h5>" + 
"<p>We will be processing your response!</p>"+
"</div"
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Here is an attempt:
[image]

Comment: Try adding these styles to the div: `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; align-items: center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
searchForm.closest("div.row").innerHTML = "<div style='color:#373737;text-align:center;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;flex-direction:column'><h5>Thank you!</h5>" + 
"<p>We will be processing your response!</p>"+
"</div"
```

Comment: Thanks! Curiously, it works when on this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/top6jbsz/3/#&togetherjs=1KiHxapGaw), but not in the print I show above.

Comment: It will work in your project also. If not then it is possible that something is conflicting

Comment: I actually had to put these style attributes into the div within which the Thank You msg's div is. Obvious, but as a beginner, these stuffs get over my head from time to time. Thanks!